# Windows 10 - Remote access failed error. Start Menu, Action Center, Cortana, cannot be opened

Tags: windows-10, filesystem-corruption

After receiving some updates from windows, right when i'm clicking one of the *Start Menu, Action Center, Volume , Battery, LAN* Button in the taskbar here is the log that i receive from event viewer.

**Event Viewer > Windows Log > Application**

**Event ID 1000 (Application Error)**

> Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.10586.306, time stamp: 0x571afaa5
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.306, time stamp: 0x571af331
>   Exception code: 0x00000004
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
>   Faulting process id: 0x1bc0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c53568a4b973
>   Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 73a7f759-ceb3-4f2e-bf8c-c1f6f38ca4c9
>   Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: App

**Event ID 1001 (Windows Error Reporting)**

> Fault bucket 133330301407, type 5
>   Event Name: MoAppCrash
>   Response: Not available
>   Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
>   P1:    >Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
>   P2: praid:App
>   P3: 10.0.10586.306
>   P4: 571afaa5
>   P5: KERNELBASE.dll
>   P6: 10.0.10586.306
>   P7: 571af331
>   P8: 00000004
>   P9: 0000000000071f28
>   P10:
>
> Attached files:
>   C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\WERCD19.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Window_659a6c6e7cf5cdf419eda5ec8d23a96c2560923a_5b8a40d8_1718d259
>
> Analysis symbol: 
>   Rechecking for solution: 0
>   Report Id: 73a7f759-ceb3-4f2e-bf8c-c1f6f38ca4c9
>   Report Status: 0
>   Hashed bucket: 9ddeac95e435f3fb4c9c72df2dbe6bd8

**Event ID 5973 (Apps)**

> Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

**Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Apps > Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational**

**Event ID 5990 (Apps)**

> Activation via contract helper of the app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with The remote procedure call failed..

**Event ID 5961 (Apps)**

> Activation of the app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call failed..

**Event ID 5985 (Apps)**

> ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with The remote procedure call failed..

I have tried to do,

1. Open Command prompt as administrator
2. dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
3. sfc /scannow
4. powershell
5. Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$*.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($*.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
6. Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

**Powershell Error Log on step 6**

> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed. Please contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
>   NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 74f7f7bd-c533-0001-dffe-f77433c5d101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 74f7f7bd-c533-0001-dffe-f77433c5d101
>   At line:1 char:28
>   + ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\Syst...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

**PS: Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 74f7f7bd-c533-0001-dffe-f77433c5d101**

> Time                      ID           Message
>   ----                      --           -------
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      301          The calling process is powershell.exe
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      603          Started deployment Register operation on a package with main parameter: AppXManifest.xml and Options: 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\bdbe6b38-9530-49e4-8225-55ec60ab3510_S-1-5-21-2804219749-2886508966-3037080736-1000_123.rslc for Register Operation on Package Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      607          Deployment Register operation on package Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy has been de-queued and is running for user GENUINE-PC\GENUINE.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      613          Adding uri to the list of Uris: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      412          error 0xD000003A: Deployment of package Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy was blocked by AppLocker.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      605          The last successful state reached was Resolved. Failure occurred before reaching the next state Approved.
>   6/13/2016 1:34:55 PM      401          Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy from:  (AppXManifest.xml)  failed with error 0xD000003A. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

It doesn't solve my problem, and try to create new user account as an Admin, Switch User, try to open the explorer and then there is a message **No Such Interface are supported**. In my main account there isn't any error when i'm trying to open the explorer.

And then, tried to start **Application Identity Service** which is stopped and end up that I can't open anything, even Ctrl+Alt+Del error, saying that the device is malfunctioning, and finally hold my power button till my laptop shut down.

People from reddit, at this **[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3tbj2c/windows_10_1511_shell_experience_host_causing/)** said that,

> Well, I ended up fixing this my copying the entire C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy path from a non-updated windows 10 system.

I just only have one laptop in here, doesn't want to reset my PC because of my data, if it is the only solution, I'm sorry if it is inappropriate, I would like to request willingly in here to upload the **C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy** path folder including the files, compress it to archive and upload to somewhere so i can replace my own.

Comment: The common denominator seems to be `Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.306` and `Exception code: 0x00000004.` I installed Windows 10 Pro from scratch 4 days ago. Everything worked fine for 2 days, then I started getting this error (when running Calculator or Store).

Comment: For anyone that looking for an answer. I solve this problem by reinstalling Windows. It was so much frustrating back then, a lot of times and efforts have been done, so I've got no other choice and reinstalled it.